# Mlflow is not writing model results to the right experiment

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, mlflow

I have created an experiment [a place to log runs] inside the workspace to track all run logs indide databricks. The code that runs isn't in the same location. MLflow is not able to pick up the already created experiment and is creating and writing to mlruns in the same directory as the code runs.

PS: I need a shared experiment where all users can log to that experiment

I can see that the experiment is created with an `experiment_id`. I am running the following code to write mlflow logs there

```
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

client = MlflowClient()


experiment = client.get_experiment_by_name('`experiment_id`')
print("Name: {}".format(experiment.name))
print("Experiment ID: {}".format(experiment.experiment_id))
print("Artifact Location: {}".format(experiment.artifact_location))
print("Lifecycle_stage: {}".format(experiment.lifecycle_stage))

with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id=experiment.experiment_id):
    mlflow.log_param('test', 1)
    mlflow.log_param('test2', 2)
    mlflow.log_param('test3', 3)
    mlflow.end_run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the experiment with `experiment_name` as below.

```
experiment = mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name='experiment_mlflow2')
print("Experiment_id: {}".format(experiment.experiment_id))
print("Artifact Location: {}".format(experiment.artifact_location))
print("Tags: {}".format(experiment.tags))
print("Lifecycle_stage: {}".format(experiment.lifecycle_stage))
```

[image]

**Note**: If there is no experiment with given name, this function will create new experiment with that name, else the experiment is used.
See [this](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.set_experiment) for more information.

Then run `mlflow.start_run()` as below, default it takes the experiment set in previous code.

See [this](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run) for more information on `mlflow.start_run()`

[image]

```
tags = {
"engineering": "ML Platform",
"release.candidate": "RC1",
"release.version": "2.2.0",
}

with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.set_experiment_tags(tags)
    mlflow.log_param('test', 1)
    mlflow.log_param('test2', 2)
    mlflow.log_param('test3', 3)
    mlflow.end_run()
```

Here you see tags updated.

[image]